# Bitbucket runner for window to build and deploy .net framework 4.8

Tags: asp.net, continuous-integration, devops, bitbucket-pipelines

Currently, I'm lost on how to build and deploy .net framework 4.8 web app using bitbucket pipeline. I saw some advice to use bitbucket runner for windows but can't find any tutorial to achieve this. Need help from someone who has experienced this before on how to write a proper bitbucket-pipeline.yaml.

Below is my current bitbucket-pipeline.yaml file that I tried to play around

```
definitions:
  steps:
    - step: &build-deploy-stg
        name: Build and Deploy
        runs-on:
          - 'stg'
          - 'windows'
          - 'self.hosted'
          - 'kentico'
        script: 
          - choco install nuget.commandline -y
          - nuget restore
          - msbuild /p:Configuration=Debug
        artifacts:
          - bin/Release/**
pipelines:
  branches:
    staging:
      - step: *build-deploy-stg
```

But when I run this pipeline, I received below error

```
HttpResponseSummary{httpStatusCode=403, httpStatusMessage=Forbidden, bodyAsString={"error":{"message":"Forbidden","detail":"Could not find runner associated with oauth client.","data":{"key":"rest-service.rest-service.forbidden","arguments":{}}}}}
```

The runner is online in my repo
[image]

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Is this feature even supported? I saw a lot of posts saying no?